struggling with stripe payment gateway in strapi CMS
I build an ecommerce website using next js. I used strapi for the cms and stripe for the payment gateway. so in the strapi backend app I added the api to make the payment operation. and this is the code
'use strict';

// @ts-ignore
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STIPE_SECRET_KEY);

/**
 * order controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::order.order', ({ strapi }) => ({
    async create(ctx) {
        // @ts-ignore
        const { products } = ctx.request.body;
        const lineItems = await Promise.all(
            products.map(async (product) => {
                const item = await strapi
                    .service("api::product.product")
                    .findOne(product.id);

                return {
                    price_data: {
                        currency: "cad",
                        product_data: {
                            name: item.title,
                        },
                        unit_amount: item.price * 100,
                    },
                    quantity: item.quantity,
                };
            })
        );

        try {
            const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
                shipping_address_collection: { allowed_countries: ['US', 'CA'] },
                payment_method_types: ["card"],
                mode: "payment",
                success_url:`${process.env.CLIENT_URL}?success=true`,
                cancel_url: `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}??success=false`,
                line_items: lineItems,
            });

            await strapi.service("api::order.order").create({ data: { products, stripeId: session.id } });

            return { stripeSession: session };
        } catch (error) {
            ctx.response.status = 500;
            return { error };
        }
    }
}));

then in the client side if user click the checkout button this is the function to handle submit
  const stripePromise = loadStripe(
    "pk_test_51P2oOLKBSRV7dryrpTP3KRN4DZKqvqj7B9cgBPib65JdpIZa5g9i2QTP8VruvddPl5zG8dq7OAa4fIoUGG8f7Ido00hVKbRT1R"
  );

  const handlePayment = async () => {
    try {
      const stripe = await stripePromise;
      const res = await makeRequest.post("/orders", {
        products: cartItemList,
      });
      await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        sessionId: res.data.stripeSession.id,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

I am expecting to go the the stripe checkout page. but it is not redirecting to there. but showing this error
AxiosError {
message: 'Request failed with status code 401',
name: 'AxiosError',
code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
config: {
transitional: {
silentJSONParsing: true,
forcedJSONParsing: true,
clarifyTimeoutError: false
},
adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
transformRequest: [ 0: λ:transformRequest ],
transformResponse: [ 0: λ:transformResponse ],
timeout: 0,
xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
maxContentLength: -1,
maxBodyLength: -1,
env: {},
headers: AxiosHeaders {
Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, /',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
Authorization: 'bearer undefined'
},
baseURL: 'http://localhost:1337/api',
method: 'post',
url: '/orders',
data:
'{"products":[{"name":"Masar Green One","quantity":3,"amount":270,"image":"/uploads/Rectangle_90_84c9813ece.png","actualPrice":100,"id":32,"product":1}]}'
},
request: XMLHttpRequest {
onreadystatechange: null,
readyState: 4,
timeout: 0,
withCredentials: false,
upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload {
onloadstart: null,
onprogress: null,
onabort: null,
onerror: null,
onload: null,
ontimeout: null,
onloadend: null
},
responseURL: 'http://localhost:1337/api/orders',
status: 401,
statusText: 'Unauthorized',
responseType: '',
response:
'{"data":null,"error":{"status":401,"name":"UnauthorizedError","message":"Missing or invalid credentials","details":{}}}',
responseText:
'{"data":null,"error":{"status":401,"name":"UnauthorizedError","message":"Missing or invalid credentials","details":{}}}',

This appears to be an authorization error between your client and your own API. That is, your POST request to your own /orders endpoint appears to be missing some expected credential. You'll need to debug that part based on the frameworks and tooling you're using.
One note for the Checkout session, though. Sessions now have a url (API ref) so you can redirect to that yourself and redirectToCheckout is no longer necessary. In fact, if you only every redirect to checkout (and don't collect payment details on your own page), then you might not need Stripe.js at all.
